# Как вывести массив в массиве через ngFor в angular в таблицу

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Не получается вывести в таблицу массив, у меня выходит что новые элементы добавляются с новой строки, а мне нужно чтобы они вывелись в одну строку, как на первом изображении, у меня получается как на втором изображении.

```
    <h1>HttpClient</h1>


    <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" >
      <td *ngFor="let f of flights ['head']">
      <tr >
           <th>{{f.name}}</th>
      </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let f of flights ['head']">
          <tr *ngFor="let subhead of f ['subhead']">
            <th>{{subhead.name}}</th>
        </tr>
      </td>

    </table>

json
{
    "head": [
    {
        "name": "№",
        "subhead": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Рейсы",
        "subhead": [
            { "name": "план" },
            { "name": "факт" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "рейсов/час",
        "subhead": [
            { "name": "9:00" },
            { "name": "10:00" },
            { "name": "11:00" },
            { "name": "12:00" },
            { "name": "13:00" },
            { "name": "14:00" },
            { "name": "15:00" },
            { "name": "16:00" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "План на смену",
        "subhead": null
    }],
    "data": [
        { "№": "1", "план": 10, "факт": 8, "9:00": 1, "10:00": 2, "11:00": 1, "14:00": 3, "15:00": 1, "План на смену": 1000 },
        { "№": "2", "план": 10, "факт": 6, "9:00": 1, "10:00": 1, "12:00": 2, "14:00": 1, "15:00": 1, "План на смену": 1000 },
        { "№": "3", "план": 10, "факт": 5, "9:00": 1, "12:00": 2, "14:00": 1, "15:00": 1, "План на смену": 1000 },
        { "№": "4", "план": 10, "факт": 12, "9:00": 2, "10:00": 1, "11:00": 2, "12:00": 2, "14:00": 3, "15:00": 1, "16:00": 1, "План на смену": 1000 },
        { "№": "5", "план": 10, "факт": 7, "10:00": 1, "11:00": 2, "13:00": 1, "14:00": 1, "15:00": 1, "16:00": 1, "План на смену": 1000 },
        { "№": "6", "план": 10, "факт": 8, "9:00": 3, "13:00": 2, "14:00": 1, "15:00": 1, "16:00": 1, "План на смену": 1000 }
    ]
}



    [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]


    [![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcvLm.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tazrK.png
```

Comment: Ваш пример невозможно воспроизвести

Comment: `<td *ngFor="let f of flights ['head']">` - а где соответствующий `tr`?